# Django + uwsgi + nginx + CentOS 7 : connection refused on 8001 port

Tags: python, linux, django, nginx, uwsgi

Django + uwsgi + nginx + CentOS 7 : connection refused on 8001 port

I get http 520 error when I tried to go to http://domain.com:8000

**nginx.conf**

```
    upstream django {
        # connect to this socket
        # server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;    # for a file socket
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;      # for a web port socket

        }

    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      8000;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name domain.com;   # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        #root /home/mysite;
        charset     utf-8;

        #Max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste


        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /home/mysite/uwsgi_params; # or the uwsgi_params you installed manually
            }


        }
```

error message on /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2015/04/09 12:28:07 [error] 23235#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 118.131.206.235, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "domain.com:8000"
2015/04/09 12:28:08 [error] 23235#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 118.131.206.235, server: domain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "domain.com:8000"
```

I've tried everything but couldn't find any clue that it gives me http 502 error.

Comment: Is your uWSGI server actually running? Is it bound to port 8001?

Answer (score 0):

SELinux may prevent such type of connection by default.

You need to check logfile /var/log/audit/audit.log to be sure about it.

Or use following command to stop SELinux for this time:

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: I disabled SELinux already, and there is no audio.log file. :(